# How do I use user input to invoke a function in Python?

Tags: python, function

I have several functions such as:

```
def func1():
    print 'func1'

def func2():
    print 'func2'

def func3():
    print 'func3'
```

Then I ask the user to input what function they want to run using `choice = raw_input()` and try to invoke the function they choose using `choice()`. If the user input func1 rather than invoking that function it gives me an error that says `'str' object is not callable`. Is their anyway for me to turn 'choice' into a callable value?

Answer (score 12):

The error is because function names are not string you can't call function like `'func1'()` it should be `func1()`,

You can do like:

```
{
'func1':  func1,
'func2':  func2,
'func3':  func3, 
}.get(choice)()
```

its by mapping string to function references

**side note**: you can write a default function like:

```
def notAfun():
  print "not a valid function name"
```

and improve you code like:

```
{
'func1':  func1,
'func2':  func2,
'func3':  func3, 
}.get(choice, notAfun)()
```

Comment: for OP: its would be an example of [**run time polymorphism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29#Subtype_polymorphism_.28or_inclusion_polymorphism.29)!! in Python

Answer (score 4):

If you make a more complex program it is probably simpler to use the cmd module from the Python Standard Library than to write something.
Your example would then look so:

```
import cmd

class example(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt  = '<input> '

    def do_func1(self, arg):
        print 'func1 - call'

    def do_func2(self, arg):
        print 'func2 - call'

    def do_func3(self, arg):
        print 'func3 - call'

example().cmdloop()
```

and an example session would be:

```
<input> func1
func1 - call
<input> func2
func2 - call
<input> func3
func3 - call
<input> func
*** Unknown syntax: func
<input> help

Undocumented commands:
======================
func1  func2  func3  help
```

When you use this module every function named `do_*` will be called when the user inputs the name without the `do_`. Also a help will be automatically generated and you can pass arguments to the functions.

For more informations about this look into the Python manual ([here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/cmd.html)) or into the Python 3 version of the manual for examples ([here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/cmd.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `locals`

```
>>> def func1():
...     print 'func1 - call'
... 
>>> def func2():
...     print 'func2 - call'
... 
>>> def func3():
...     print 'func3 - call'
... 
>>> choice = raw_input()
func1
>>> locals()[choice]()
func1 - call
```

Comment: or more generally, `globals`