# How do i condense multiple elif statements (python)

Tags: python

I just want this code to be smaller. This long line of essentially nothing is rely bothering me.

```
    shop()
  elif y == ("u"):
    upgrade()
  elif y == ("st"):
    storage()
  elif y == ("f"):
    factory()
  elif y == ("d"):
    debug()
  elif y == ("a"):
    alchemy()
  elif y == ("h"):
    helpzone()
  elif y == ("sa"):
    saving()
  elif y == ("c"):
    conquest()
```

There is just a  input before it. How would I condense this? Thanks.

Comment: Use a dictionary with the code as key and the function to call as value.

Comment: This post might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881409/whats-an-alternative-to-if-elif-statements-in-python